# What's with the abysmally slow deployment to Android AVDs?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

`adb push` is a crying shame, performance-wise. Uploading a couple of megs to an AVD - essentially, copying it from one disk file to a chunk in another file **on the same physical box** - shouldn't take that long. It takes less to pull the same file over the 'Net, with a decent connection.

The target is emulated, ARM on Intel, so on, so forth. I get it. But see this timing:

- Uploading a project to AVD: **1 min 42 sec**
- Uploading the same to a device over USB: **7 sec**
- Downloading the same app from the 'Net on the same AVD: **50 sec**

What kind of a local machine connection is it that is twice as slow as the big wide Internet?

That was the rant; now's the question. Short of debugging on a device all the time, any workarounds, please?

My APK is mostly code. I can eliminate *some* data to speed it up, but that's just 1 MB out of roughly 6.

A radical solution would be some kind of a rewrite of whatever transport ADB uses to talk to the AVD. Right now, it sounds like forwarded TCP sockets; but does it have to be that way? I'm sure the emulator platform is capable of sharing a memory chunk and a mutex between host and device.

Comment: The problem is probably not the communication, but that you are talking to an **emulated** system, likely hosted on a resource-constrained box.  Hardly anybody uses this method for routine development, but only for occasional tests of specifics which cannot be tried on their available hardware devices.

Comment: "Hardly anybody"??? I doubt that. I do, anyway, on six different mobile platforms :) And anyway, downloading off the 'Net on the same emulated device, with the same emulated TCP/IP stack, goes twice as fast. No, this **is** communication to some degree. And the host hardware is quite decent.

Comment: Yes, "Hardly anybody" because the emulator is *slow* and that costs money.  Devices are cheap, and better representative of what users experience anyway - so **android** emulators primarily get used only to temporarily test something when a specific version matching device isn't available, or when the platform itself needs to be tweaked/probed in ways not possible on a secured device.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that way. Windows Mobile emulator back in the old days performed on par with a device. iOS simulator performs pretty much at the speed of host hardware, but that's an unfair comparison.

Comment: Those are not **emulating** a foreign processor architecture, they are running the application code on a thin interface translation/privilege trap layer atop the host system.

Comment: WinMo emulated ARM to a tee. iOS indeed doesn't. And anyway, my second point stands.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly , you'r saing that eclipse AVD is too slow. Well there is Genymotion an alternative standalone android v-machine.Its fast and you just drag the app on it to install it in 3-4 seconds.The only drawbacks are: -It has some limitations at the free version witch will not bother you if you dont make too advanced apps and -you need to exprt the .apk and drag it on the emulator (~10sec?). It is faster than phone debbug or eclipse AVD for me.
You can get it here: [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Can you debug on it? Does it take NDK?

Comment: No, you cant debug on it, as i've mentioned you need to build your project and install it there.